# Is there any limitation to Share Point Collect Feedback Workflows Comment Box?

Tags: 2013, workflow, document, limitations, comments

I am creating several collect feedback workflows for my company to review multiple documents. The goal is to set one workflow for each document, but several documents are 100 pages long and there will be quite a bit of feedback that will be provided. I wanted to see, is there a limit of how many characters in the comment box when collecting feedback through the workflow? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried in Sharepoint 2013 (activating the Collect Feedback Workflow from 2010) And works well with more than 12000 characters (twelve thousand).
Doing some research I've found an useful link about SharePoint storing textareas as "nText" SQL Type.

[What is the max limit for number of characters in multiline text in Sharepoint?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5e8cc504-03d0-4d26-81f9-1608c2c5881f/what-is-the-max-limit-for-number-of-characters-in-multiline-text-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)